# How to create non changeable date using moment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

Why this function changing time to indian time. I want to set it as same as written in code. So that I can compare it with current indian time. How can I do that?

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment.parseZone('2016-04-12T03:52:57+05:30'))
```

Comment: can u try ==> moment.locale('en-IN')
just after require

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada No it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse the date as UTC.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
console.log(moment.utc('2016-04-12T03:52:57+05:30'))
```

Otherwise, moment will read it as local time.